# SoapClient not working in php, How to fix it on mac osx

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm getting the following error: "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from "url"". I'm trying to load a soap request but when
I create a new SoapClient with the url, I got an error.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'url?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($url);

?>
```

Comment: Check that the URL is correct and accessible.

Comment: I've already checked and the url works perfectly. I tried on windows computer with the same code and works.

Comment: Can you access the URL from a browser on the same Mac where you have an issue? It doesn't make a lot of sense, seems lime maybe could even be a networking issue or something. Shame you don't get a more detailed error about why it fails. As a test can you make PHP successfully download the WSDL data with a simple file_get_contents()?

Comment: See if it works with http instead of https. If so, PHP is having trouble establishing a secure connection, and you'll need to set some options in the SoapClient constructor.

Comment: Nice, I tried with http and works. ;D

Comment: Unfortunately, getting it to work with HTTPS can be kind of a pain in my experience. A lot of the answers you'll find here suggest disabling verification, which is not the right way to do it.

Comment: You are right, but for this time I'm using it for developer purposes, for real intentions the https is a must.